# what is the order of css style evaluation?

Tags: css

I am new to css so pardon if this is very basic. But I have element in my html page like this

```
<div  id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
```

And in my css I have following:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background: yellow !important;
    color: blue !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    border: none;
}

.ui-widget-content .ui-datepicker { 
    background: blue; !important;
    border: 1px solid #555; !important;
    color: red; !important;
}
```

With this I expected my ui-datepicker element to have background of blue however it always turns out to be yellow. No matter where I place .ui-wdget-content. If I want to have css where all ui-widget-element to have background of yellow, except the ui-datepicker to have background of blue. What is the css incantation I have to do?

Comment: Try changing `.ui-widget-content .ui-datepicker {` to `.ui-widget-content.ui-datepicker {`. The space means apply to a descendant.

Comment: Uh, shouldn't your code be: `<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker" style="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">`

Comment: background: blue; !important; wont work. Needs background: blue !important; Extra semi-colan

Comment: @zyboxinternational those aren't "styles", they are "classes".

Comment: @showdev Correct me if I'm wrong (I probably am in this case), but wouldn't the HTML require the `ui-widget`, `ui-widget-content` (etcetera) classes to be present?

Comment: @zyboxinternational Nope. HTML will ignore classes that don't exist.

Comment: Er.. I should say the browser will ignore them..

Comment: @zyboxinternational How so? I've never gotten an error for referenceing a class that doesn't exist. The defualt styles will be applied.

Comment: @Adelphia True, but isn't that just the browser's HTML parser 'correcting' the page layout as it loads? If so, couldn't this cause problems later-on?

Comment: It corrects syntax as it loads, it doesn't change the attributes AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

`.ui-widget-content .ui-datepicker` should be `.ui-widget-content.ui-datepicker` (no space)

There is no `ui-datepicker` class inside any `ui-widget-content`, instead you want to select the element with both classes.

Comment: Indeed removing the spaces between .ui-widget-content and .ui-datepicker fixes my issue. Also there was ';' after blue that i had to remove. But now leaves me confused I see many style sheets where they have things say like: .ui-menu .ui-menu-item { background: transparent; } so how does the space between class specification interpreted by css? Is is it like class that has ui-menu AND class that has ui-menu-item apply the background style?

Comment: `.a .b` selects anything with class `b` which is inside anything with class `a`. `.a.b` selects anything with class `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually telling is:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content"> background yellow  </div>

<div class="ui-widget-content> yellow too
   <div  class="ui-datepicker" > background blue </div>
</div>
```

And ultimately int the priority to apply styles the inline style it's at the top

```
<div style="background-color: " >
</div>
```

Check these: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/ 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: Thank you for that multiple-class-id-selector link helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're having this

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-datepicker {
```

But according to your HTML

```
<div  id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
```

your CSS should be

```
.ui-widget-content.ui-datepicker {
```

This would select the element for you.